# How to search multiple value(domain name) in a single request in Elasticsearch?

Tags: api, elasticsearch

Previously I have done this (Added data to elasticsearch) :-

```
**URL :** localhost:9200/testrdr/supp_domains/_bulk (Put request)

**Raw Data (json) :** 
{ "create" : { "_index" : "testrdr" } }
{ "domain-name": "r1.com" }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "testrdr"} }
{ "domain-name": "r2.com" }
............................................ upto "r100.com"
```

Then searched for a single domain :-

```
**URL :** http://localhost:9200/testrdr/_search (Post request)

**Raw Data (json) :** 
                         {     
                           "query":{
                               "query_string":{
                                    "query":"r10.com",
                                        "default_operator": "and"
                                 }
                               }
                             }

Output was this : 
                {
                "took": 4,
                "timed_out": false,
                "_shards": {
                    "total": 5,
                    "successful": 5,
                    "skipped": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                },
                "hits": {
                    "total": 1,
                    "max_score": 11.104812,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "_index": "testrdr",
                            "_type": "supp_domains",
                            "_id": "SPvtSGIB_duJQL0ByfXm",
                            "_score": 11.104812,
                            "_source": {
                                **"domain-name": "r10.com"**
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

As you can see a single document showing there in the output as per the query .
**Now I want to search for multiple domain . Means, I want to know If [r1.com,r20.com,r50.com] these three domains are exits or not ? with valid output like previous section**

Note : I am using "Postman" application for sending request

Comment: Do you want to check if all those domains exist in the index, or just return those that match?

Comment: return those that match

Comment: Did you consider using [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query?